# Are there non-lazily evaluated "and" or "or" operations in Common Lisp?

Tags: boolean, common-lisp, lazy-evaluation

The usual `and` and `or` operators in Common Lisp will lazily evaluate their operands, e.g. the `and` will stop once it encounters the first `nil`. I am searching for an operator that does not work this way, but instead always evaluates all operands before returning a result. Is there something like this?

In C for example you have the lazy `&&` and you have the bitwise `&`, which can be used as a non-lazy alternative.
I know about `logand` and `bit-and`, but those do not work on boolean operands.

E.g.:

```
(and NIL (not-defined))
```

would not throw an error, but i want it to throw one.

Comment: `In C for example you have the lazy &&` - it's not laziness but short-circuit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(defun and* (&rest l)
  (every #'identity l))
```

or returning the last value if all true

```
(defun and& (&rest l)
  (or (null l)
      (loop for b in l
            unless b
              do (return nil)
            finally (return b))))
```

or

```
(defun and& (&rest l)
  (or (null l)
      (loop for b in l
            always b
            finally (return b))))
```

Comment: With this definition `(and 1 2)` gives `2`, `(and* 1 2)` gives `T`

Comment: @6502: see and&

Answer (score 2):

A possible implementation is

```
(defun and* (&rest x)
  (let ((res T))
    (dolist (item x)
      (if (null item) (return-from and* item))
      (setf res item))
    res))
```

Explanation:

- We initialize the result to `T` (this is needed because `(and)`→`T`)
- We loop over the arguments
- If an argument is `NIL` then we return it
- Otherwise we store the item as result
- If we get to the end of the loop then we return last item

The implementation of `or*` is simpler because the only "falsy" value in Common Lisp is `NIL` so there's no need to remember what is the last falsy element and you can just use `some`...

```
(defun or* (&rest x)
  (some #'identity x))
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative implementation for `and*`:

```
(defun and* (&rest values &aux (res t))
  (every (lambda (v) (setf res v)) values)
  res)
```

This returns the last non-nil value or `nil`.

Comment: +1 for elegance, but I think you need to use `&aux (res T)` because `(and*)` is supposed to return `T`, not `NIL`.